# How to find the forces from rigid body simulations

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

With Blender's built in rigid body physics simulation, its possible to simulate complex mechanical systems like the cam and follower shown below. The animation below shows how the simulation can capture complex behaviors like rotation and translation due to forces on the different bodies,

[image]

Is there a way to determine the forces at the points of contact in a rigid body physics simulation?

Comment: with default blender AFAIK - no.